# Serial communications with a USB to Serial converter on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

I have an FTDI chip based USB to serial converted that I will at one point try to communicate to a TV with via RS232.  I am running Ubuntu Maverick.

I'm new to serial communications and can't figure out why I can't simply read bytes from the port.

A serial loopback test was successful.  I shorted Tx and Rx together and ran the following C program and my keyboard was echoed on the screen.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    struct termios tio;
    struct termios stdio;
    int tty_fd;
    fd_set rdset;

    unsigned char c='D';

    printf("Please start with %s /dev/ttyS1 (for example)\n",argv[0]);
    memset(&stdio,0,sizeof(stdio));
    stdio.c_iflag=0;
    stdio.c_oflag=0;
    stdio.c_cflag=0;
    stdio.c_lflag=0;
    stdio.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    stdio.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
    tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSANOW,&stdio);
    tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&stdio);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);       // make the reads non-blocking




    memset(&tio,0,sizeof(tio));
    tio.c_iflag=0;
    tio.c_oflag=0;
    tio.c_cflag=CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;           // 8n1, see termios.h for more information
    tio.c_lflag=0;
    tio.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tio.c_cc[VTIME]=5;

    tty_fd=open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    cfsetospeed(&tio,B115200);            // 115200 baud
    cfsetispeed(&tio,B115200);            // 115200 baud

    tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&tio);
    while (c!='q')
    {
            if (read(tty_fd,&c,1)>0)        write(STDOUT_FILENO,&c,1);              // if new data is available on the serial port, print it out
            if (read(STDIN_FILENO,&c,1)>0)
            {
              write(tty_fd,&c,1);                     // if new data is available on the console, send it to the serial port
            }
    }

    close(tty_fd);
}
```

I then plugged the USB side into a USB (/dev/ttyUSB0) port on my PC and the 9-pin side of the cable to the serial port (/dev/ttyS0).

I ran the previous program on /dev/ttyUSB0 and typed in another terminal window:

```
echo "Hello world!" > /dev/ttyS0
```

Nothing appears.  I also tried running the program in two separate terminals on both /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyS0 and I couldn't communicated from one to the other.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a loopback test with /dev/ttyS0?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to configure both usb serial and db9 serial ports. (ie baud rates, hardware , flowcontrol, etc.) stty or setserial are two linux commands that could accomplish this, check on the man pages or examples online.

After that you should be able to pipe strings into the devices and it should work.